# How can I fully remove Ubuntu 12.04 from my MacBook Pro?

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, macbook, mac, dual-boot

I want to remove Ubuntu 12.04 from my MacBook Pro.
It's a trial boot system, with MacOS in the first partition, Windows 7 in the second one, and Ubuntu in the last.
Now, I want to format this last one, in order to expand the Windows partition.

I tried to do this from MacOS, but I could not.

Everyone can help me, please?
(when I insert the ubuntu live CD, after some initial boot screens, the command line says that it can't find the medium... It cannot see my ubuntu CD!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved.
The problem was that I tried with a live CD of Ubuntu 10.04. After a lot of workarounds (for instance, I can boot from the live distro only if there are both CD and USB plugged in!), I solved using the Ubuntu 12.04 live CD, and gParted.

Thank you to everyone who wanted to help me!

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to accomplish this.  The easiest way is to boot from your Ubuntu Live CD or USB device.

Once the Ubuntu desktop has loaded, start *Disk Utility* (gparted).

Next, find your Ubuntu partion(s) and format them all as free space.  Next, resize your Windows partition (NTFS) to consume the rest of the disk.  Accept the operations and wait for a few moments.

That's it!

Good luck.  :)

Comment: As I wrote in my first comment, I tried this, without lucky. Is there a way to format the partition from MacOS?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to format it with an Ubuntu live CD.

Comment: It's exactly what I tried. But when I insert the CD, after some initial boot screens, the command line says that it can't find the medium... It cannot see my CD!

Comment: how did you install ubuntu then?

Comment: have you tried this with an other linux distro, or an usb thumbdrive with ubuntu on it.

Comment: did you press c before booting the live cd; becouse acording to this support page by apple:http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1533 you got to press c to boot from a cd.

Comment: I installed the distro from the live CD. Now, I cannot use the same CD as a live distro... And this happens also when I try with an USB live...

Comment: Did you use disk ultility on mac os to format the ubuntu partion

Answer (score 0):

OS-Uninstaller is a small graphical tool to perform a clean and quick uninstall of any operating system (Windows, OS X, MacOS, Ubuntu, other Linux distributions...) from your computer.

#### Features

- It supports removing only selected OS boot list entries in the GRUB.

  [image]
- Or completely remove the GRUB and replace it with the original MBR (master boot record) that was there before installing Ubuntu.
- It also automatically reformats the partition of the OS that you just removed into NTFS (default) or ext4, depending on the OS that was there before.
- Change the GRUB menu’s display timeout.
- Backup the partition table and the boot sectors (just in case).
- It also lets you manually change the MBR and its installed location of hard disk and the partition it’s linking for booting. But for most users, you don't have to tweak any of these.

Download [Boot-Repair-Disk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/). Then create a live USB flash drive of it.

In order to make a Boot-Repair live USB, use [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/). The flash drive you use should be 1GB or larger and formatted to FAT32. The formatting procedure will delete all of the files that are already on the flash drive.

In UNetbootin click the *Diskimage* radio button and then click the   <kbd>**...**</kbd>   button.

[image]

Select the boot-repair-disk ISO file that you downloaded and click the *Open* button.

It is **very important** to verify that the device that you are installing the boot-repair-disk ISO to is indeed your flash drive, so that you don't overwrite any of your system or personal files which may make your operating system unbootable. In OS X you can find the device name of the USB flash drive using Disk Utility.

In the first screenshot the name of the USB drive is `/dev/disk0s4`

To boot the Boot Repair live USB on a Mac:

1. Insert the USB drive into an available USB port.
2. Reboot or turn on the Mac.
3. Immediately after the startup chime, press the Option key (sometimes marked Alt).
4. Select the USB drive from which to boot by using the left and right arrow and Enter keys.

Boot from the Boot Repair live USB. A window (Boot-Repair) will appear, close it. Then launch OS-Uninstaller from the bottom left menu.