# Dual BOOT with TWO Ubuntu : How to remove one of them?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have a problem.

I have a dual boot with two Ubuntu : how to remove one of them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fully remove Ubuntu 12.04 from my MacBook Pro?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152652/how-can-i-fully-remove-ubuntu-12-04-from-my-macbook-pro)

Comment: @guiverc Also in EFI mode you have to take care of the boot-loader. If single ESP both installs will use `EFI/ubuntu` as location for grub. Maybe best to reinstall the boot-loader from the install you want to keep with `sudo grub-install`(no need to specify device, it's always the ESP which is mounted on `/boot/efi`) first and then remove the partition(s) of the install you want to remove. After that in the remaining install `sudo update-grub` is required.